# Qt, Qml and C++ based application porting to Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

I am porting Qt(C++) and qml based app to Android platform. I am **not using Qt Creator** because of the nature of the project.

I have done compiling the code using ndk and generated all the required .so files for my C++ components. Created the project in Android studios, included the jiniLibs(`*.so`) files, alos, used Qt provided Activity/Loader/Delegate classes and to write Android app. App loads the "main.so" and application get started. I can see the logs which tells me that its loaded. I have created `QGuiApplication` object and while creating `QmlComponent`, I am trying to pass `main.qml` into `QmlComponent instance` within `main.so` but I don't know how to specify the path of `main.qml`?

I tried `qrc:/main.qml`, `assets:/main.qml` but no luck.

NOTE: I placed my `main.qml` in `assets` folder. I am not even sure when to put that file while packaging.

Looking for suggestion, how do we specify assets/resource paths inside C++ code.

Comment: Read the documentation on the [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

Comment: Qt Android helper classes copy all the assets at

`/data/data/org.qtproject.example.test/qt-reserved-files/` but you need to make sure that assets information should be in `libs.xml` which has a section `<array name="bundled_in_assets">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt Android helper classes copy all the assets at `/data/data/org.qtproject.example.test/qt-reserved-files/` path but you need to make sure that assets information should be mapped in `res/values/libs.xml` which has a section

Answer (score 0):

```
// QQmlEngine* m_pQmlEngine;
m_pQmlEngine->setBaseUrl("qrc:/qml/");
```